# Unable to understand non-standard HTML tags found in VBA macros (<F:/U> and <F:/font>)

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm not familiar with this syntax, but I found <F:/li> in the following VBA code snippet (and others in the attached screenshot) where an HTML email body is constructed. Is "F" a namespace? a class? How does it get resolved?

[image: Code snippet]

```vb
     With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To = EmailCell2
        .CC = "PanelAnalyticsTeam@nielsen.com"
        .BCC = ""
        .From = """Panel Analytics"" <Panel.Analytics.US.TAM@nielsen.com>"
        .Subject = "Membership Score Card Report " & Format$(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        .HTMLBody = "<body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>Hello " & PersonCell & "," _
                    & "<br><br>Attached is the Membership Score Card report for " & Tdate & ". The file contains the following tabs:<br><br>" _
                    & "<F:/li><li>Current Work</li><br>" _
                    & "<F:/li><li>Individual Performance for year to date (12/1/16 to 11/30/2017)</li><br>" _
                    & "<F:/li><li>Individual Performance for the last 90 days</li><br>" _
                    & "<F:/li><li>Individual Performance for the last 30 days</li><br>" _
                    & "<F:/li><li>Assignment Summary (currently under construction)</li><br>" _
                    & "<font face=""Calibri"" size=""2"" color=""black"">Note: The there are columns that are still being developed in each tab.</font></b><br>" _
                    & "<br><font face=""Calibri"" size=""3.5"" color=""red"">Attention Manager: Do not share hours worked information among associates.</font></b><br>" _
                    & "<br>Please contact our team with any questions or enhancements regarding this report." _
                    & "<br><br>Thank you,<p>Panel Analytics"
        .AddAttachment EName
        .Send
    End With
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Nathan_Sav. I still can't understand where this prefix was defined or how it could be resolved.